# How to send form values to the route of the controller using Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

is it possible to send variables that are in the form, to the route of a controller?

Example:

FormType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {    
        $builder->add('status', 'entity', array( 'class' => 'ADVD:Status', 
                        'label'   => 'form.country', 
                        'translation_domain' => 'ADVDBundle',
                        'empty_value'=> '- Select -', 
                        'property' => 'name'))

                ->add('country', 'entity', array(
                        'class' => 'ADVD:Country', 
                        'label'   => 'form.country', 
                        'translation_domain' => 'ADVDBundle',
                        'empty_value'=> '- Select -', 
                        'property' => 'description'));

    }
```

Controller:

```
 public function groupPrizesRequestedAction($status = 0, $country = 0) {
        switch ($status) {
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            case 6:
                break;
            case 7:
                break;
            case 8:
                break;
            case 9:
                break;
            case 10:
                break;
            case 11:
                break;
            default:
                $formulario = $this->createForm(new GroupingType());
                return $this->render('ADVDBundle:Prize:groupIndex.html.twig', array('form' => $formulario->createView())
                );
                break;
        }
    }
```

Template:

```
    {% block body %}
    <form action="{{ path('advd_status', {'status': X, 'country': X}) }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
{{ form_widget(form) }}
            <input class="input_button" type="submit" value="Search" />
        </form>
{% endblock %}
```

The GroupIndex template is a search template, the idea is that after those values are selected from a dropdown you press search and it searches with the parameters of country and status that the form sends, the thing is I don't know how to make the controller receive those values because I don't know what to put here  `path('advd_status', {'status': X, 'country': X})` and I need them to the switch on the Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can submit form and get form data in controller(not need to specify it in url)

```
{% block body %}
    <form action="{{ path('advd_status') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        <input class="input_button" type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

In controller

```
 public function groupPrizesRequestedAction($status = 0, $country = 0) {
    $formulario = $this->createForm(new GroupingType());
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $data = $formulario->getData();
        $status = $data->getStatus();
        switch ($status) {
            ...
        }
    }
   else {
      return $this->render('ADVDBundle:Prize:groupIndex.html.twig', array('form' => $formulario->createView());

   }  
}
```

[Forms chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) in symfony book

Comment: Hi. Thank you for answering. I had a 7month period of no programming and I forgot the most basic things. Thanks